# Golang bug or intended feature on map literals?

Tags: go

Just started to learn Go and I need map of string string, that I initialize literally.

```
mapa := map[string]string{
        "jedan":"one",
        "dva":"two"
       }
```

But compiler is complaining `syntax error: need trailing comma before newline in composite literal`

So I had to add coma after `"two",` or delete a new line and have `}` after last value for compiler to be happy

Is this intended behavior of code style?

EDIT: to be clear follwing will compile and work

```
mapa := map[string]string{
        "jedan":"one",
        "dva":"two"  }
```

`go version go1.4.2 darwin/amd64`  Mac OSX 10.9.5

Comment: BTW: gofmt your code. And if you ever have to read or approve a diff you'll start appreciating Go's style.

Comment: Go is a quite opinionated language. This is one of those opinions. The more you fight it, the more you will dislike the language. Just submit to the Gods and all will be well.

Comment: It wont gofmt `missing ',' before newline in composite literal`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Go has semicolons, but you don't see them because they're inserted automatically by the lexer.

[Semicolon insertion rules](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Semicolons):

> a semicolon is automatically inserted into the token stream at the end of a non-blank line if the line's final token is
>
> - an integer, floating-point, imaginary, rune, or **string literal**

So this:

```
mapa := map[string]string{
    "jedan": "one",
    "dva":   "two"
}
```

is actually:

```
mapa := map[string]string{
    "jedan": "one",
    "dva":   "two";  // <- semicolon
}
```

Which is invalid Go.

Comment: Wow!  This certainly violates POLA - a bit of a blemish to a beautiful, simple language that is golang (relative to C++).

Comment: POLA = Principle of Least Astonishment.  The formal reason — yeah quite surprising — but the actual error message doesn't say confusing stuff like "missing } before ;"...  It says "need trailing comma before newline in composite literal" which is very clear and not astonishing .  I do prefer Python's definition of "logical line can't end until you closed all )]}", and semicolon insertion had a history of astonishing people in JS, but I guess in Go they more carefully made astonishing scenarios invalid?  At least I never hit one.

Answer (score 16):

Yes it is. And you should choose the added comma.

It is much more simple to edit map/slice literals that way : you can copy-paster, move items around without worrying about the fact that the last item shouldn't be followed by a comma.

In fact, you can also do the same in PHP, javascript, and many other languages.

Comment: I don't see much difference in having one more new line , I'll edit a question to be more specific

Comment: I guess nobody understood my question, the first code snippet wont compile , but second one will compile  , in PHP JS first snippet is legit !

Comment: Well, your question was "Is it the intended behavior that I have to add a comma at the end of the line or remove the newline". And the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

mapa :=[]map{
"jedan":"one",
"dva":"two"
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).